# RavenDB 2.5.2874 sql replication questions\problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, ravendb

1. is It possible to reset the replication configuration on a certain collection **without using the studio** (exist a client api?);
2. I tried to delete a replication configuration using both session.Delete(mySqlReplication) and store.DatabaseCommands.Delete(keyMySqlReplication, etagMySqlReplication) but exceptions where thrown, how can i delete a replication configuration **without using the studio**?;
3. Updating an existing replication configuration (using client api, simply with a load and save) don't cause the update of sql table (i need to reset the replication config like at point 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update it without using the studio.
The studio is not a privileged client, so it doesn't do anything special that you cannot do from the client API.

In particular, you need to be aware that it is likely that the document is being modified while you are writing it, and retry if you get a concurrency exception.

You need to update the status document to reset the process, not the configuration

Comment: "_You need to update the status document to reset the process, not the configuration_" basically this solve all my problems. ty